# What is more performant in Linq multiple order by?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, sql-order-by

which of the sorted lists below is more performant:

```
var sortedList = data.OrderBy(row => row.Fullname).ThenBy(row => row.Age);
```

or this one:

```
var sortedList = from row in data 
                 orderby row.Fullname, row.Age
                 select row;
```

Comment: Minor note; `sortedList ` isn't actually a sorted list; it is a sequence using deferred execution. The distinction may be important when the source data is changed after the query is created, or when it is iterated multiple times, etc;

Comment: Since you've written it both ways already **try it and see**. Then you'll know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query syntax is being converted to Method syntax by compiler, so they are the same.

Answer (score 6):

They both will be converted to the same expression.

Comment: In particular (for the OP's benefit), note that the final `select row` is completely removed (by the compiler / language-spec) in this example; so they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

That is both the same. There will be no difference.its more about how you like typing